# Is it possible to replace the variable arrows in PCA gg-plot with points and labels only?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

```
ggbiplot(PCA),biplot<-ggbiplot(pcobj = PCA, choices= c(1,2),scale = 1, groups =Fdata$Tissue,ellipse = TRUE)+ geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 3)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 3)+ geom_point(aes(shape=factor  (Fdata$Tissue)))    + guides(color = "none", shape = guide_legend(title = "Tissue")) + scale_shape_discrete(labels = c("Flesh","Gill"))
```

Comment: Can you explain what does "variable arrows with points and labels only"? Do you want to remove arrows?

Comment: Yes @Park, i want to remove the arrows but keep it as points with labels. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Argument `var.axes` will control arrows.

```
ggbiplot(ir.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,groups = iris$Species, ellipse = TRUE, var.axes = FALSE)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 3) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=factor(iris$Species))) +
  guides(color = "none", shape = guide_legend(title = "Tissue")) +
  scale_shape_discrete(labels = c("Flesh","Gill", "wow"))
```

[image]

## Code for your case

```
ggbiplot(PCA),biplot<-ggbiplot(pcobj = PCA, choices= c(1,2),scale = 1, groups =Fdata$Tissue,ellipse = TRUE, var.axes = FALSE)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 3)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 3)+
  geom_point(aes(shape=factor  (Fdata$Tissue)))    + 
  guides(color = "none", shape = guide_legend(title = "Tissue")) + 
  scale_shape_discrete(labels = c("Flesh","Gill"))
```

## Some more manual version

```
x <- ggbiplot(ir.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,groups = iris$Species, ellipse = TRUE, var.axes = TRUE)
df.v <- x$plot_env$df.v
ggbiplot(ir.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,groups = iris$Species, ellipse = TRUE, var.axes = FALSE)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 3) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=factor(iris$Species))) +
  guides(color = "none", shape = guide_legend(title = "Tissue")) +
  scale_shape_discrete(labels = c("Flesh","Gill", "wow")) +
  geom_point(data = df.v,
             aes(x = xvar, y = yvar),
             color = ('red')) +
  geom_text(data = df.v, 
            aes(label = varname, x = xvar, y = yvar, 
                angle = angle, hjust = hjust), 
            color = 'darkred', size = x$plot_env$varname.size)
```

[image]

Comment: i have tried with var.axes=False, but it removes the arrows completely and what i want to do is to keep the points for the arrows with its labels. And is it possible actually to do that?

Comment: @SonamTashi That's not possible just using `ggbiplot`. You might need to get component of `pca` object manually using `geom_point` and `geom_text`.

Comment: thank you, so will scatter plot be able to do as what i have described?

Comment: Yes. In source code, it used `geom_segment` and `geom_text`. Originally, there is no points exists to variables, only arrows and points. You may take a look at [source code](https://github.com/vqv/ggbiplot/blob/master/R/ggbiplot.r). Tell me if you can't handle with this code.:D

Comment: thank you. I couldnt get around with the code. could you model the argument in my context?

Comment: @SonamTashi I add code above.